# python threading wont start in background

Tags: python, multithreading, inline

this is my class for turn on , turn off , and blink LED in raspberry pi
i want stop thread blink in some time ...
but thread wont run in background ...

> class LED:
>
> ```
> _GPIOPORT=None
> flagstop=0
> flag=threading.Event()
>
>
> def __init__(self,GPIONUM):
>     self._GPIOPORT=GPIONUM
>     GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
>     GPIO.setwarnings(False)
>     GPIO.setup(self._GPIOPORT, GPIO.OUT)
>     self.flag.set()
>     
>     
> def TurnOn(self):
>     self.flag.clear()
>     print 'Turn On ...'
>     GPIO.output(self._GPIOPORT,True)
>     
> def TurnOff(self):
>     self.flag.clear()
>     print 'Turn Off ...'
>     GPIO.output(self._GPIOPORT,False)
>     
> def Blink(self,delay,e):
>     print 'Thread Blink Create ...'
>     t1=threading.Thread(self.BlinkThread(delay,e))
>     t1.start()
>     print 'Thread Started'
>     
> def BlinkThread(self,delaytime,event):
>     print 'BlinkTrehad Start ....'
>     while not event:
>         GPIO.output(self._GPIOPORT,False)
>         sleep(delaytime)
>         GPIO.output(self._GPIOPORT,True)
>         sleep(delaytime)
> ```

and this is my module for use this class :

```
import LED
from time import sleep
import threading

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        e=threading.Event()
        e.set()
        ledblue=LED.LED(11)
        ledblue.TurnOn()
        sleep(1)
        ledblue.Blink(1,e)
        ledblue.TurnOn()
```

never "Thread Started" print in consol and loop run in line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling BlinkThread() in the Thread constructor instead of just passing the function reference and arguments and letting the thread start the function. Change it to:

```
def Blink(self,delay,e):
    print 'Thread Blink Create ...'
    t1=threading.Thread(target=self.BlinkThread, args=(delay,e))
    t1.start()
    print 'Thread Started'
```

Comment: but give me this error 
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 438, in __init__
    assert group is None, "group argument must be None for now"
AssertionError: group argument must be None for now

Comment: oops, my bad. should have been target=..., I will fix